# Force due to a snake

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Suppose that I am running fast in a field when I find a snake in front of me. I stop quickly. Which force is responsible for my deceleration?
I can relate it as it is due to my hormones but how can I relate with the force?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your legs will apply force on the ground, and its reaction will slow you down as dictated by $F=ma$. What is your question?

Comment: Which force will try to decelerate?

Comment: I don't know who have downvoted my question but atlease give reason for downvote so I can try to improve it.

Comment: What forces have you considered and why? Let us know that you have gone beyond "some force."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider all forces acting on the body:

1. Weight
2. Contact forces

Weight acts vertically downwards and contact force has horizontal and vertical components.The vertical component of contact force balances weight and the only force acting in horizontal direction is horizontal component(friction) of contact force.

So friction is the only external force which can stop you.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by waveion, your legs will apply force on the ground at an angle whose "opposite-to-your-motion" component will decelerate you.

To see how, consider how you move forward? You apply a force forming an acute angle to the ground in direction of motion. The vertical component of that force makes sure you don't sink into the ground. Other words, it balances your weight. The horizontal components lets you move forward by gaining reaction from the ground and overcoming friction. While slowing down, you apply a force at an obtuse angle whose horizontal component is "back-wards" aka against your motion and hence you stop.